# How much money would it take to artificially inflate/depress a stock?

Tags: options, hedge-fund

Please include links or at least keywords to research papers if possible.

This is basically an investigation into max pain / stock pinning and what it would take for a hedge fund to cause it.

Some inputs

- market capitalization
- Institutional versus retail ownership
- Transparency of business model
- Implied volatility, Strike, time to expiry
- availability of shares to short

The reason I ask is the behavior of HTZ this week seemed peculiar and the PUT options were priced very high.

I do understand that this is a boogey man with options and I'm not looking for answers to pinning/max pain manipulation, but rather just the simple question of what is required to influence a stock price and if there has been any studies done on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the recent work by Koijen and Gabaix tries to tackle precisely a similar question.

They do not have a paper yet. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apCxV8zxoOc

They find that buying 1% of the market increases prices by 5-12%. I.e. markets are inelastic. So if this is true for the market, I am assuming for individual stocks would be even worse.

[image]

Comment: Are there other studies on buying a different proportion. Like, say if I buy 2% of the market how much will I increase the stock price by?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer a similar question recently here: [How can we estimate new stock price after a large purchase?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54786/how-can-we-estimate-new-stock-price-after-a-large-purchase/54788#54788)

Whilst it might not be *exactly* what you might be looking for, it might help you understand the problem in a practical context.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that regular pension fund contributions inflate the average stock prices with the [inelastic price multiplier of order 5](https://ssrn.com/abstract=3686935).  Further developments of this concept have been discussed by [Bouchaud](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3896981) and [myself](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4473754).  There is a lot of literature on single-stock price impact in ArXive and SSRN, too.